# Converting Matrix to CGAffineTransform

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics

I've developed an app on Android, where you can add images on the screen and pan/rotate/scale them around. Technically, I have a fixed-aspect parent layout, which contains these images (ImageViews). They have set width and height to match_parent. Then, I can save their positions on the server, which I can then load later on same or other device. Basically, I simply save Matrix values. However, translation x/y have absolute values (in pixels), but screen sizes differ, so instead I set them as percentage values (so translation x is divided by parent width and translation y is divided by parent height). When loading images I just multiply translation x/y by parent layout width/height and everything looks the same even on the different device.

Here's how I do it:

```
float[] values = new float[9];
parentLayout.matrix.getValues(values);

values[Matrix.MTRANS_X] /= parentLayout.getWidth();
values[Matrix.MTRANS_Y] /= parentLayout.getHeight();
```

Then in loading function, I simply multiply these values.

Images manipulation is done by using postTranslate/postScale/postRotate with anchor point (for 2-finger gesture it's midpoint between these fingers).

Now, I want to port this app to iOS and use the similar technique to achieve correct images positions on iOS devices as well. CGAffineTransform seems to be very similar to Matrix class. The order of fields is different, but they seem to work the same way.

Let's say this array is the sample values array from Android app:

```
let a: [CGFloat] = [0.35355338, -0.35355338, 0.44107446, 0.35355338, 0.35355338, 0.058058262]
```

I don't save last 3 fields, because they're always 0, 0 and 1 and on iOS they can't be even set (documentation also states it's [0, 0, 1]). So this is how the "conversion" looks like:

```
let tx = a[2] * width //multiply percentage translation x with parent width
let ty = a[5] * height //multiply percentage translation y with parent height
let transform = CGAffineTransform(a: a[0], b: a[3], c: a[1], d: a[4], tx: tx, ty: ty)
```

However, this only work for very simple cases. For other ones image is usually misplaced or even completely messed up.

I've noticed that, by default, on Android I have anchor point in [0, 0], but on iOS it's image's center.

For example:

```
float midX = parentLayout.getWidth() / 2.0f;
float midY = parentLayout.getHeight() / 2.0f;

parentLayout.matrix.postScale(0.5f, 0.5f, midX, midY);
```

Gives the following matrix:

```
0.5, 0.0, 360.0, 
0.0, 0.5, 240.0, 
0.0, 0.0, 1.0
```

[360.0, 240.0] is simply a vector from the left-top corner.

However, on iOS I don't have to provide mid point, because it's already transformed around center:

```
let transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.5, y: 0.5)
```

and it gives me:

```
CGAffineTransform(a: 0.5, b: 0.0, c: 0.0, d: 0.5, tx: 0.0, ty: 0.0)
```

I've tried setting a different anchor point on iOS:

```
parentView.layer.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
```

However, I cannot get the right results. I've tried translation by -width * 0.5, -height * 0.5, scale and translate back, but I don't get the same result as on Android.

In short: how can I modify Matrix from Android to CGAffineTransform from iOS to achieve the same look?

I'm also attaching as-simple-as-possible demo projects. The objective is to copy output array from Android into "a" array in iOS project and modify CGAffineTransform calculation (and/or parentView setup) in way that image looks the same on both platforms no matter what's the log output from Android.

Android:
https://github.com/piotrros/MatrixAndroid

iOS:
https://github.com/piotrros/MatrixIOS

**edit:**

@Sulthan solution is working great! Althought, I've come up with a subquestion of reversing the process, which I also need. Using on his answer, I've tried to incorporate into my app:

```
let savedTransform = CGAffineTransform.identity
        .concatenating(CGAffineTransform(translationX: -width / 2, y: -height / 2))
        .concatenating(
            self.transform
        )
        .concatenating(CGAffineTransform(translationX: width / 2, y: height / 2))

let tx = savedTransform.tx
let ty = savedTransform.ty

let t = CGAffineTransform(a: savedTransform.a, b: savedTransform.b, c: savedTransform.c, d: savedTransform.d, tx: tx / cWidth, ty: ty / cHeight)

placement.transform = [Float(t.a), Float(t.c), Float(t.tx), Float(t.b), Float(t.d), Float(t.ty), 0, 0, 1]
```

placement is just a class to hold "Android" version of matrix. cWidth / cHeight is width/height of parent. I divide tx/ty by them to get percentage width/height, just like I do on Android.

However, it doesn't work. tx/ty are wrong.

For input:

> [0.2743883, -0.16761175, 0.43753636, 0.16761175, 0.2743883,
>   0.40431038, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]

it gives back:

> [0.2743883, -0.16761175, 0.18834576, 0.16761175, 0.2743883, 0.2182884,
>   0.0, 0.0, 1.0]

so everything else other then tx/ty is fine. Where's the error?

Comment: How about change all layer.anchorpoint to x:0, y:0, or x:0 y:1.  We know it’s pivot question. The right origin can save you A lot of work.

Comment: Yeah, I know. I thought it's a simple error, but I just cannot find the right settings. I've tried both (x: 0, y: 0) and (x: 0, y: 1) pivots and it's wrong. Just try it yourself on demo projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem is that in Android you set the the transform for the parent layout which then affects the children. However on iOS you have to set the transform on `imageView` itself. This is common for both solutions below.

**Solution 1: Updating Anchor Point**

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
    imageView.bounds = parentView.bounds
    imageView.layer.anchorPoint = .zero
    imageView.center = .zero

    let width = parentView.frame.width
    let height = parentView.frame.height

    let a: [CGFloat] = [0.35355338, -0.35355338, 0.44107446, 0.35355338, 0.35355338, 0.058058262]

    let tx = a[2] * width
    let ty = a[5] * height
    let transform = CGAffineTransform(a: a[0], b: a[3], c: a[1], d: a[4], tx: tx, ty: ty)

    imageView.transform = transform
}
```

**Important:** I have removed all constraints for `imageView` from the storyboard

We have to move view `anchorPoint` to the top-left corner of the image to match Android. However, the non-obvious problem is that this will also affect the position of the view because view position is calculated relative to the anchor point. With constraints it starts to be confusing, therefore I removed all constraints and switched to manual positioning:

```
imageView.bounds = parentView.bounds // set correct size
imageView.layer.anchorPoint = .zero // anchor point to top-left corner
imageView.center = .zero // set position, "center" is now the top-left corner
```

**Solution 2: Updating Transform Matrix**

If we don't want to touch the anchor point, we can keep constraints like they are and we can just update the transform:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    let width = parentView.frame.width
    let height = parentView.frame.height

    let a: [CGFloat] = [0.35355338, -0.35355338, 0.44107446, 0.35355338, 0.35355338, 0.058058262]

    let tx = a[2] * width
    let ty = a[5] * height
    let savedTransform = CGAffineTransform(a: a[0], b: a[3], c: a[1], d: a[4], tx: tx, ty: ty)

    let transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
        .translatedBy(x: width / 2, y: height / 2)
        .concatenating(savedTransform)
        .concatenating(CGAffineTransform(translationX: -width / 2, y: -height / 2))

    imageView.transform = transform
}
```

The non-obvious problem with `CGAffineTransform` is the fact that

```
.concatenating(CGAffineTransform(translationX: -width / 2, y: -height / 2))
```

and

```
.translatedBy(x: -width / 2, y: -height / 2)
```

are not the same. The multiplication order is different.

[image: iOS]

**Reversing the process:**

To generate the same matrix to be used for Android, we simply have to move the origin:

```
let savedTransform = CGAffineTransform.identity
    .translatedBy(x: width / 2, y: height / 2)
    .scaledBy(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
    .rotated(by: .pi / 4)
    .translatedBy(x: -width / 2, y: -height / 2)
```

or using concatenation:

```
let savedTransform = CGAffineTransform.identity
    .concatenating(CGAffineTransform(translationX: -width / 2, y: -height / 2))
    .concatenating(
        CGAffineTransform.identity
            .scaledBy(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
            .rotated(by: .pi / 4)
    )
    .concatenating(CGAffineTransform(translationX: width / 2, y: height / 2))
```

With concatenation it is now obvious how the origin transformations cancel-out.

**Summary:**

```
func androidValuesToIOSTransform() -> CGAffineTransform{
    let width = parentView.frame.width
    let height = parentView.frame.height

    let androidValues: [CGFloat] = [0.35355338, -0.35355338, 0.44107446, 0.35355338, 0.35355338, 0.058058262]
    let androidTransform = CGAffineTransform(
        a: androidValues[0], b: androidValues[3],
        c: androidValues[1], d: androidValues[4],
        tx: androidValues[2] * width, ty: androidValues[5] * height
    )

    let iOSTransform = CGAffineTransform.identity
        .concatenating(CGAffineTransform(translationX: width / 2, y: height / 2))
        .concatenating(androidTransform)
        .concatenating(CGAffineTransform(translationX: -width / 2, y: -height / 2))

    return iOSTransform
}

func iOSTransformToAndroidValues() -> [CGFloat] {
    let width = parentView.frame.width
    let height = parentView.frame.height

    let iOSTransform = CGAffineTransform.identity
        .scaledBy(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
        .rotated(by: .pi / 4)
    let androidTransform = CGAffineTransform.identity
        .concatenating(CGAffineTransform(translationX: -width / 2, y: -height / 2))
        .concatenating(iOSTransform)
        .concatenating(CGAffineTransform(translationX: width / 2, y: height / 2))

    let androidValues = [
        androidTransform.a, androidTransform.c, androidTransform.tx / width,
        androidTransform.b, androidTransform.d, androidTransform.ty / height
    ]
    return androidValues
}
```

Comment: I've tried solution #2, because that was initial idea and it indeed worked! My mistake was not using "concatenating".

Comment: Just one subquestion: how can I convert back CGAffineTransform to Android's Matrix?

Comment: @Makalele Updated

Comment: @Makalele Added full conversion code. I hope that will make everything clear.

Comment: Yes. Now I got it working. Looks like I passed wrong width/height. Now it's correct. Big thanks!

Answer (score 0):

How about this answer:  I add four sliders to make things much easy to see.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var parentView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


}




let width =  UIScreen.main.bounds.width
let height = UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 2.0 / 3.0


var zoom: CGFloat = 1.0
var rotate: CGFloat = 0.0

 var locX: CGFloat = 0.0
 var locY: CGFloat = 0.0

@IBAction func rotate(_ sender: UISlider){  //0-6.28

    rotate = CGFloat(sender.value)
    parentView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: rotate).concatenating(CGAffineTransform(scaleX: zoom, y: zoom))
    parentView.transform.tx = (locX-0.5) * width
    parentView.transform.ty = (locY-0.5) * height
}

@IBAction func zoom(_ sender: UISlider){ //0.1 - 10

    zoom = CGFloat(sender.value)
    parentView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: rotate).concatenating(CGAffineTransform(scaleX: zoom, y: zoom))
    parentView.transform.tx = (locX-0.5) * width
    parentView.transform.ty = (locY-0.5) * height
}

@IBAction func locationX(_ sender: UISlider){  //0 - 1

    locX = CGFloat(sender.value)
    parentView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: rotate).concatenating(CGAffineTransform(scaleX: zoom, y: zoom))
    parentView.transform.tx = (locX-0.5) * width
    parentView.transform.ty = (locY-0.5) * height
}

@IBAction func locationY(_ sender: UISlider){ //0 - 1
    locY = CGFloat(sender.value)
    parentView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: rotate).concatenating(CGAffineTransform(scaleX: zoom, y: zoom))
    parentView.transform.tx = (locX-0.5) * width
    parentView.transform.ty = (locY-0.5) * height
}



override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
  let a: [CGFloat] = [0.35355338, -0.35355338, 0.44107446, 0.35355338, 0.35355338, 0.058058262]
    let tx = (a[2] - 0.5) * width
   let ty = (a[5] - 0.5) * height
let transform =  CGAffineTransform(a: a[0], b: a[3], c: a[1], d: a[4], tx:tx, ty: ty)
parentView.layer.anchorPoint   = CGPoint.zero
parentView.layer.position = CGPoint.zero
parentView.transform = transform

}
```

}

Comment: I've tried that however still got wrong result. Just run demo projects from android / iOS and see the results.

Comment: I run iOS version and looks ok.

Comment: It looks like this on android: https://imgur.com/a/k9JOC1k and on iOS: https://imgur.com/a/QkyRCjV

Comment: looks similar, but it should a bit lower so it's still something wrong

Comment: 0.058058262 is pretty close to the top. You may add some views above to low the position.